# Changing number in beamer and changing it back

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Matrix}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),ampersand replacement=\&] (m)
{
  8 \& 8 \& 1 \& 6 \\
  3 \& 8 \& 5 \& 7 \\
  4 \& 8 \& 9 \& 5 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to make the slide so that when I click, the number 1 in the matrix changes to 2 and also changes its color to blue, and when I click again, it goes back to 1 in black. Is this possible to do in Beamer? I read the documentation about `\alt` and some other commands, but they don't seem to help.

I guess I can just make two new slides and copy everything over and just change the one number, but I wonder whether there's a solution using just the one slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\only<nums>{<stuff>}` overlay specification to print `<stuff>` on select `<nums>` frames:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Matrix}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=),ampersand replacement=\&] (m)
  {
    8 \& 8 \& \only<1,3>{1}\only<2>{\textcolor{blue}{2}} \& 6 \\
    3 \& 8 \& 5 \& 7 \\
    4 \& 8 \& 9 \& 5 \\
  };
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Now if you meant that you want to click on the number and the slide should turn, that can also be done via hyperlinks. However, it's less elegant if you plan on jumping back-and-forth between slides, only to resume your presentation.