# replacing number in a matrix

Tags: beamer

I am including a game in my beamer presentation using the package sgamevar. I would need to change the content of the cells in the matrix, after I present the game. Just to state things clearer. I would like that in the third page of my slide, the number 2 in the first cell appears underlined and red. I tried with \only option, but this simply add an underlined and red 2 instead of replacing the original number. Below is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{sgamevar}

\newenvironment{stepenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}[<+->]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemize}{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}{\end{itemize} }
\newenvironment{stepenumeratewithalert}{\begin{enumerate}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{enumerate}}
\newenvironment{stepitemizewithalert}{\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]}{\end{itemize} }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Strategic Form Games}
\framesubtitle{Nash Equilibrium - The Battle of Sex}
\begin{stepitemizewithalert}
\item This is the solution of the game:\medskip
\pause[2]
\begin{figure}\renewcommand{\gamestretch}{2.5}
\ssualfalse
\begin{game}{2}{2}[P1][P2]
      \> $FB$      \> $FW$ \\
$FB$ \> $2,1\only<3>{{\textcolor{red}{\underline{2}}},1}$ \> $0,0$\\
$FW$ \> $0,0$   \> $1,2$
\end{game}
\end{figure}
\end{stepitemizewithalert}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Could you please give me a suggestion on how to overcome my problem?

All the best,

Dario

Comment: See, if answer of question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294908/changing-number-in-beamer-and-changing-it-back can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though using `\only<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨text⟩}` works, I would recommend to use `\alt<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨default text⟩}{⟨alternative text⟩}` here. It is intended for exactly this case.

```
$FB$ \> $\alt<3>{\textcolor{red}{\underline{2}}}{2},1$ \> $0,0$\\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$FB$ \> $\only<3>{{\textcolor{red}{\underline{2}}}}\only<2>{2},1$ \> $0,0$\\
```

Comment: Thanks @Eliad and@Benjamin. Both solutions work fine. Problem solved.